# Infura is not working with Nader Dabit tutorial for NFT Marketplace. How can I use Infura again?

Tags: nft, ethers.js, hardhat, infura, ipfs

I was trying to build an NFT Marketplace demo using Nader Dabit tutorial. Whenever I try to click on 'Create an NFT' button after file submission, I run into an Unhandled Runtime Error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

When I inspect the issue, it returns a random string in CID, which is not identified as an url by the program. Here's my 'create-nft.js' where all this issue is caused -

```
/* pages/create-nft.js */
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { create as ipfsHttpClient } from 'ipfs-http-client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'

const projectId = process.env.INFURA_IPFS_PROJECT_ID;
const projectSecret = process.env.INFURA_IPFS_PROJECT_SECRET;
const projectIdAndSecret = `${projectId}:${projectSecret}`

const client = ipfsHttpClient({
  host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
  port: 5001,
  protocol: 'https',
  headers: {
    authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(projectIdAndSecret).toString(
      'base64'
    )}`,
  },
})

const authorization = "Basics" + btoa(projectId + ":" + projectSecret);

import {
  marketplaceAddress
} from '../config'

import NFTMarketplace from '../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarketplace.sol/NFTMarketplace.json'
import { Bytecode } from 'hardhat/internal/hardhat-network/stack-traces/model'
import { notEqual } from 'assert'

export default function CreateItem() {
  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState([null])
  const [formInput, updateFormInput] = useState({ price: '', name: '', description: '' })
  const router = useRouter()

  async function onChange(e) {
    /* upload image to IPFS */
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    try {
      const added = await client.add(
        file,
        {
          progress: (prog) => console.log(`received: ${prog}`),
        }
      )
      const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`

      client.pin.add(added.path).then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        setFileUrl(url)
    })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error uploading file: ', error)
    }  
  }
  async function uploadToIPFS() {
    const { name, description, price } = formInput
    if (!name || !description || !price || !fileUrl) return
    /* first, upload metadata to IPFS */
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      name, description, image: fileUrl
    })
    try {
      const added = await client.add(data)
      const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`
      /* after metadata is uploaded to IPFS, return the URL to use it in the transaction */
      createSale(url)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error uploading file: ', error)
    }  
  }

  async function listNFTForSale() {
    const url = await uploadToIPFS()
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()

    /* create the NFT */
    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(formInput.price, 'ether')
    let contract = new ethers.Contract(marketplaceAddress, NFTMarketplace.abi, signer)
    let listingPrice = await contract.getListingPrice()
    listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()
    let transaction = await contract.createToken(url, price, { value: listingPrice })
    await transaction.wait()

    router.push('/')
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col pb-12">
        <input 
          placeholder="Asset Name"
          className="mt-8 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, name: e.target.value })}
        />
        <textarea
          placeholder="Asset Description"
          className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, description: e.target.value })}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="Asset Price in Eth"
          className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, price: e.target.value })}
        />
        <input
          type="file"
          name="Asset"
          className="my-4"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        {
          fileUrl && (
            <img className="rounded mt-4" width="350" src={fileUrl} />
          )
        }
        <button onClick={listNFTForSale} className="font-bold mt-4 bg-pink-500 text-white rounded p-4 shadow-lg">
          Create NFT
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm unable to create an NFT and store it on Infura IPFS. Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue? I even downgraded the ethers.js to 5.6.1

Comment: See https://ethereumnodes.com/ for alternatives for Infura

Answer (score 1):

the infura public gateway was deprecated in August 2022
https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ipfs/how-to/access-ipfs-content/public-gateway.
I've been using lately the https://web3.storage/, which has a free tier option.

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you please post the code on how to use web3.storage?